# Command Click event of an item of an Expanded ListView not working Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, expander

I have an observable Collection of Groups and each group contains a number of Participants. So far I have an expandable list view using an Expander and everything is shown fine [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxr7E.png).

However, when I tap on a participant item nothing happens and the tap gesture doesn't fire the command method in the ViewModel. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Frame>
            
                <Expander>
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Grid Padding="10" >
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Expander.Header>

                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Participants}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Frame CornerRadius="10" Padding="10" Margin="10">
                                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}"/>
                                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="5">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}">
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </DataTemplate>  
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Expander> 

            </Frame>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The ViewModel Class

```
 public class MySessionDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private SessionDto _selectedSession;
    public SessionDto SelectedSession
    {
        get => _selectedSession;
        set
        {
            _selectedSession = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<GroupDto> _groups;
    public ObservableCollection<GroupDto> Groups
    {
        get => _groups;
        set
        {
            _groups = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    } 
    
    private ObservableCollection<ParticipantDto> _participants;
    public ObservableCollection<ParticipantDto> Participants
    {
        get => _participants;
        set
        {
            _participants = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand SelectedCommand { get; }

    public MySessionDetailViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService) : base(navigationService, dialogService)
    {
        SelectedCommand = new Command(OnParticipantTapped);
    }

    public override async Task InitializeAsync(object session)
    {
        SelectedSession = (SessionDto)session;

        Groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupDto>(SelectedSession.Groups);

        Participants = Groups.Select(x => x.Participants).FirstOrDefault().OrderBy(f => f.Number).ToObservableCollection();
    }

    private void OnParticipantTapped()
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<SurveyViewModel>();
    }

}
```

Comment: is `SelectedCommand` defined on the same class as `Name`, or is it defined in the parent VM?

Comment: SelectedCommand is an ICommand defined in the ViewModel yes. There is no code in the class behind the view, only in the viewmodel

Comment: that is not what I asked.  Is it defined on the same class as Name?  You have not provided a source, so by default it will assume it is defined at the same level.  If you are not sure, please post the code for your VM.

Comment: I don't really understand exactly what you mean but ye I have the command defined in the same ViewModel. I posted also the ViewModel class now.

Comment: your ItemsSource is Participants, so each row in your layout has a BindingContext of ParticpantDTO.  SelectedCommand is NOT defined on ParticipantDTO, it is defined on your base VM.  You need to provide a relative binding - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings